# Image is displayed in the center of the container with fixed height. If the width changes, it will change automatically according to the width

Tags: javascript, html, css, center

this Question about css html or? JS.

the target image have width 5120px, height 1200px.
need achieve height 600px .

---

let me use pic show u what i want to achieve.

Target:

50% Size:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoaI5.jpg)

100% Size:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG2N9.jpg)

---

But that's all I can do right now

50% Size
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CBXC.jpg)

100% Size

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM4TA.jpg)

the banner1.jpg is the big image, have width 5120px, height 1200px.

thanks u a lot~~~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="image-div">
    <img class="image-show" src="./banner1.png" alt="">
</div>

<style>

    .image-div{
      display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 600px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .image-show {
        flex: none;
    }

    .grid-layout{
        min-width: 1200px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
    }
    

    .content{
        min-width: 1200px;
        grid-column: 2/3;
        background: #b5a87f;
        text-align: center;
        height: 300px;
    }

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was done!!!!

show u the code:

html:

```
<div class="real-div">
    <div class="image-div">
        <img class="image-show" src="./banner1.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .real-div{
        position: relative;
    }
    .image-div{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        z-index: 1;
        min-width: 1200px;
    }

    .image-show {
        min-width: 1200px;
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
        object-position: center;
        object-fit: cover;
        /*cursor: pointer;*/
    }
```